# how to do regex search using variable in ansible

Tags: regex, variables, ansible

```
VLAN: "200"

- name: vlan details 
  ios_command:
    commands:
      - "show VLAN"           
  register: VLAN_status

- name: search vlan
  set_fact:
    serach_vlan: "{{ VLAN_status.stdout[0] | regex_search('^{{ VLAN }}\\s',multiline=true) }}"
```

It should capture the vlan value 200 if it is configured but it is not capturing. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the documentation:

> moustaches don’t stack

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names*</sup>

You should use [concatenation `~`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators) instead:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    serach_vlan: "{{ VLAN_status.stdout[0] | regex_search('^' ~ VLAN ~ '\\s',multiline=true) }}"
```